# Cannot dismiss or snooze reminders

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, reminder

I seem to have encountered a zombie reminder that doesn't want to die. A few weeks ago I had an issue where I had a reminder from weeks gone by pop up in my Reminder window in Outlook 2010. Due in: 2 weeks overdue. Weird, I thought.

So I did the usual 'Dismiss'. 2 seconds later:

```
"1 Reminder, Due in 2 weeks overdue".
```

Weird, I thought. So I tried snoozing it.

Not 2 seconds later:

```
"1 Reminder, Due in 2 weeks overdue".
```

Ok, this is getting weird. Let's try 'Dismiss All'.

```
"1 Reminder, Due in 2 weeks overdue".
```

Fine, fine, you win Outlook. Let's open the item and delete it.

```
"1 Reminder, Due in **3** weeks overdue".
```

Ah, now the previous reminder in the series is popping up. Let's delete that one too.

```
"1 Reminder, Due in **4** weeks overdue".
```

I ended up having to delete all past occurances of a weekly reminder before the reminder removed itself.

It's now a few weeks later, and what do I see?

```
"1 Reminder, Due in 2 weeks overdue".
```

Does anyone know if this is a known bug in Outlook 2010 Beta, where recurring events with reminders start zombifying themselves, and won't stop reminding me they exist til I decapitate (delete) them entirely?

Comment: I had this issue a couple of months ago, and like you it was a total showstopper for a while. Killing Outlook processes got me out of the loop. Only happened once, never again, and not (yet) on the RTM version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is still occuring you can always start outlook with the switch /cleansniff which should get rid of duplicate reminders. Worth a try.
Then try /cleanreminders to clear and reset all reminders (eg show you all future ones which you have snoozed or dismissed etc). Use switches as part of command to start outlook, eg:

```
<path to outlook>\outlook.exe /cleansniff
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across this as an issue with Office 2010. However you can use the [Send-a-frown feature](http://blogs.technet.com/office2010/archive/2009/07/15/tell-us-what-you-think-about-office-2010-technical-preview.aspx) to let Microsoft know and post on the [Microsoft Office 2010 Tech Preview Forum.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/office2010general/threads)

Have you installed [Hotfix for ‘Issue with message sizes in Outlook 2010 Beta’ for 32 /64-bit Office 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/outlook/archive/2010/02/11/fix-for-message-size-issue-in-outlook-2010-beta.aspx) - it's a long shot but you never know.